# iOS make a request locally

Tags: ios, request, local

Is there a way to save a JSON file within my app and whenever I need something, I would make a request and get what I need? Or maybe there is another better way beside Core - Data?
What I am trying to do with my app is to request for some musical notes, each note having it's individual properties. I would like that if I go to a song-view, to display the portatives with notes and syllables.

Snippet from my JSON file :

```
 "notes":[   
            {
                    "note_type" : "0",
                    "note_syllable1" : "Twink",
                    "note_syllable2" : null,
                    "note_length" : "0"
            },
            {
                    "note_type" : "0",
                    "note_syllable1" : "le,",
                    "note_syllable2" : null,
                    "note_length" : "0"
            },
            ....
```

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to know how to store a file, [there is a link.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use caching policies of NSURLConnection - it's supported out of box, just tune it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I needed :

```
     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testmodel" ofType:@"json"] 
                                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
     SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
     NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
```