# What is best place to store images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, xcode4.5

I want to develop a Photo Journal app, which will allow users to take pictures, record videos and arrange them in albums. What is the best place to save images. Should I save them into Documents folder or any other place. Please be kind!

Comment: u can add the images to database...

Comment: duplicate like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430935/best-way-to-store-images-in-ios

Comment: Use the Caches Directory...

Comment: @IronManGill Apple says about Documents:   Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app, such as user-generated content.
The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

Comment: @IronManGill Why did you suggest Caches Directory? I guess Chaches directory is now called Library?

Comment: Yeh so store it in the Caches directory ... read about it..

Comment: Caches Directory was suggested for iOS 5.0 and downloaded data that can be redownloaded

Comment: The cache directory is not a good place for this type of content.  Otherwise it will be deleted if disk space gets low, resulting in a loss of data that is not restorable.

Comment: @ankityadav: bad suggestion, never save images to database (store images in document directory and save the relative path to database).

Comment: Thanks to all! But I am still confused Documents or Chaches?

Comment: @MidhunMP but we have blob in sql specially for images,if m not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's user generated data, store the images and videos in the `NSDocumentDirectory`