# Storing Hundreds of Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, backend

I'm trying to determine what would be the best route to go for an app idea I have in regards to using a back-end service or not.

The app will not require any sign up / log in steps

The concept does have a part of taking a photo. For example, a photo could be taken every day, or multiple photos per day, equaling 365 + photos.

I'd like for the user to be able to view these photos at any time, and possibly export them all at once in some form (if that is possible) at any time.

What's the best way of doing this to have a good experience in the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to store images in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430935/best-way-to-store-images-in-ios)

Comment: Also consider compression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394491/how-to-compress-resize-image-on-iphone-os-sdk-before-uploading-to-a-server

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you'd define a good experience in terms of photo storage by being quick. You really don't have many options. You could either write 365+ photos into your documents directory or write them into a CoreData store. I'd probably opt for the CoreData store, because I have a feeling you're going to have some metadata associated with the image.

Really though, this question is a bit too specific to your situation. See also [Best way to store images in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430935/best-way-to-store-images-in-ios)