# iPhone .ipa and file extraction

Tags: iphone, ipa

I am writing an app for the iphone platform. My code is mostly C++ with some Objective-C code to interface with ios sdk apis. I am not very versed on iphone programming and this is my first app, so problem is that i need to read a binary file, using C++ code, containing some data but i don't kown how to do it. My concern is: can i use directly fopen/fread? Which path should i use? I come from Android development. The .apk is a simple .zip archive, so one just need to extract in memory the needed file and process it, or extract the file in a temporary directory and read it in the usual way, but i do not know how to to the same in the case of an iPhone application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the core question you're asking has already been asked and answered. You want to read and write files, but aren't confident about how/where to do so: [Write a file on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios)

Comment: Although maybe the distinguishing factor is your C++. Still, the directory structure and method of reading / writing is the same. (Albeit different in nomenclature.)