# Property List not saving iOS

Tags: ios, caching, plist

I have a property list in my application and I have it change the values of all the different fields but when the app is closed all the settings are removed. Here is the code I'm using:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
    //NSNumber *str = [dict objectForKey:@"Auto_Save"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on] forKey:@"Auto_Save"];
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write back to a file stored in the application bundle.  You need to write it to 'disk'.

Comment: Just get a path to your documents folder (or Library folder, or whatever) and write the file there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios

Comment: So I need to recreate the file?

Comment: Yes; you can't write to the application bundle - it is read-only, which is what you're attempting to do in your code sample.

Comment: I tried doing what they did in the link you sent me but that didn't work; when I debug it and have it return the value changed it does change it just doesn't save. Is it possible that I could just cache the file?