# How to insert and get the file in iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file, nsfilemanager

I am working iOS development, Is it possible to insert the file in device and then to get that file to my application. I saw a file-manager app in app-store and its share the files using bluetooth, itunes connect and wifi options. How to do like this? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

I want to upload doc or docx file and manage my app.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios  ... also take a look to apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html