# ipad - write NSString to text file

Tags: ios, file, text, insert

I have text file `text.txt` in my xcode project and I need to write NSString init from my iOS app. I've tried this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"text.txt"];
NSString *content = @"Test";
[content writeToFile: docFile atomically: NO];
```

But it doesn't work for me... So can you help me with it?

Comment: looks fine. I cant test now. Try removing `.txt`...

Comment: Look at stack's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios

Comment: I don't know, what's wrong... I have text.txt in my Resources folder in Xcode and when I try to read it, it is ok, but when I want to write something new init, it doesn't work... :-( Have you any solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
//Method writes a string to a text file
-(void) writeToTextFile{
        //get the documents directory:
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
            (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/text.txt", 
                                                      documentsDirectory];
        //create content - four lines of text
        NSString *content = @"Test";
        //save content to the documents directory
        [content writeToFile:fileName 
                         atomically:NO 
                               encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                                      error:nil];

}
```

Comment: Do not build a path using `stringWithFormat:`. Append it properly using `NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];`