# Why can't I save files to my iOS apps /Documents directory?

Tags: ios, writetofile

I am writing an app that can access the iOS root system, the user should be able to save files to his document directory. I am using this code to save the file to the document directory.

For Text:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[self.filePath writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, [self.filePath lastPathComponent]]
                                           atomically:YES
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

For other files:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[self.filePath writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,[self.filePath lastPathComponent]]
                                           atomically:YES];
```

My problem is I can save .txt files, but not other files, If I save for example .plist files with the  save text methods, the contact is replaced by the directory path of the file. When I save a picture, or any other file it isn't readable. Is there a good method to save files without destroying them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have an example of saving the image:

assuming you get the content of the image into NSData object:

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

then write it to a file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Have a look into these questions for more detailed explanations:

[Write a file on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios)

[Save An Image To Application Documents Folder From UIView On IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821517/save-an-image-to-application-documents-folder-from-uiview-on-ios)

Comment: So the element before writeToFile is an NSData?

Comment: Thanks, this was so obvious.

Answer (score 7):

You're calling `[self.filePath writeToFile:]`, thus writing the contents of the `filePath` variable to a file.

You should do something like:

```
[contents writeToFile:...]
```