# Persistent data in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to create an iPhone application:

1 - I need to have a form for the user to insert data (Text);

2 - The data needs to be saved so I can edit, view or delete a record.

3 - I need to export the data to excel ...

What is the best way to save data so it is persistent?

Is it possible to export it to Excel format?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily save your file in [CSV (comma separated value) format](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComma-separated_values&ei=WF_QUpfgMIaCyAGvjIDwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFhaCl_jtQNMLsLnUqUVf3UB0Tb6Q&bvm=bv.59026428,d.aWc), which Excel knows how to easily import.

And as for "where to save it", you can use a number of different iPhone API's (e.g. [you can "`writeToFile:`" into the documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios), or save the file to iCloud, [or can persist your data in a Core-Data database](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/gain-a-basic-understanding-of-ios-core-data/), or e-mail the document to yourself or somebody else at the end).  These are all implementation details that depend on what you want your application to look like.