# writetofile always returns false

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to write content to a file in swift

```
let jsonResult = try!   NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data, options:   NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary   

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

let documentDirectory = urls.first!.path
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory!).URLByAppendingPathComponent("data.txt")
let dict = jsonResult as NSDictionary
let status = dict.writeToFile(path.path!, atomically: false)
print(status)
```

But content is not written to file and status is always false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 2**

```
        let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

        let jsonResult : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(object: "08:00:00", forKey: "start_hour");
        jsonResult.setValue("10:00:00", forKey: "end_hour");
        jsonResult.setValue("30", forKey: "call_duration");

        let dict = jsonResult as NSDictionary

        if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
            let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dir as String).URLByAppendingPathComponent(file);

            //writing
            dict.writeToFile(path.path!, atomically: false)

            var contents : NSString
            //reading
            do {
                contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path.path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            }
            catch {
                /* error handling here */
                contents  = ""
            }
            print(contents as String);
        }
```

If you already have a file in bundle, Use following code to find path and read file.

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample-text", ofType: "txt")

    let contents: NSString
    do {
        contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch _ {
        contents = ""
    }
```

Parse Web service response :

```
        // responseData - API response data.

        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        let getConfig: NSDictionary
        do {
             getConfig = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary
        } catch  {
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        }
```

Comment: stringByAppendingPathComponent does not work in xcode 7(deprecated) .which is why i used URLByAppendingPathComponent.

Comment: I am using xcode 7.1. I didn't get deprecated issue. however, I have updated code.

Comment: Have you test above example?. Is it fix your issue @jithin ?

Comment: Yes this works with your content as json but does not work with my json data.

Comment: @jithin, Are you handle the web service response data?

Comment: yes response data is json serialised and then converted to dictionary before writing to file

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to your application's bundle. Instead, try writing to your application's documents directory. See this question: [Write a file on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios)

Comment: @Aron Wojnowski I tried that first.Please see my modified quetion